# tvOS UISegmentedControl not matching appearance settings

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, tvos

In my tvOS app, I have a UISegmentedControl and when switching selected segment or leaving focus from the UISegmented control, there is a strange animation and the font and color appearance doesn't match any of my configured appearance settings. See the attached .mov.
Any suggestions on correcting this?

Screen capture:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/70kiobvagrri23n/UISegmentedControl.mov?dl=0

```
    if let font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 18.0) ?? UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18.0),
        let select = leaderboardSelect {

        let attrsNormal: [AnyHashable: Any] = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow]
        select.setTitleTextAttributes(attrsNormal, for: .normal)
        select.setTitleTextAttributes(attrsNormal, for: .highlighted)
        select.setTitleTextAttributes(attrsNormal, for: .disabled)
        select.setTitleTextAttributes(attrsNormal, for: .selected)
        select.setTitleTextAttributes(attrsNormal, for: .application)
        select.setTitleTextAttributes(attrsNormal, for: .reserved)

        let attrSelected: [AnyHashable: Any] = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orange]
        select.setTitleTextAttributes(attrSelected, for: .focused)
    }
```